# Declarate class members during runtime in C#

Tags: c#, class, microsoft-metro, runtime

I'm trying to build a small Win 8.1 app using Visual Studio 2013 with XAML/C#.

What I want to do is to generate a class whith member variables which are defined in another class. To be more exact: I have a class where all the definitions are stored as a list like this:

```
class def
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<string> Att =new List<string>();

}
```

During runtime, I load instances of this class via

```
List<def> DefInfoFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<def>>(json);
```

What I want to do now is to create a new class with the member variables of type Type and name Name (the attributes are not important here).

Something like this is sadly not possible:

```
 class obj(DefInfoFromJson)
{
    foreach(def object in DefInfoFromJson)
    {
    object.Type object.Name;
    }

}
```

Example:
The list contains three items:
1. Name="ID", Type="int"
2. Name="Firstname", Type="string";
3. Name="Lastname", Type="sting";

shich should lead to the follwing class:

```
class obj
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

}
```

I hope the objective/my problem is clear.
Is there a way to do this? I've read about "Reflection Emit" but I don't get it at the moment and I am not shure if it is the right way to do this.

Thank you alot for your help!

Comment: What do you expect to *do* with this afterwards? Would a `Dictionary<string, string>` not do just as well? Or perhaps use `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: I expect to use this objects to gather some informating through the user of the app via textboxes. I'm not shure if a dictionary is a possibility, if so I don't now how to use it. ExpandoObjects sounds interesting but I first have to check this since I never used it before. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: as a side note, "int" and "string" are not a good type names. `int` is a keyword that refers to System.Int32, but you wouldn't be able to do `Type.GetType("int")`. Instead, you would need `Type.GetType("Int32")`. So you might want to keep that in mind as well.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez How do you mean that `int` and `string` aren't good types? Arent they the normal types in c#?